# How to efficiently Configure Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a React Project where we make webpack to run it from local and cloud systems But here is a small workaround we need to do every time we run it in cloud .

```
const devWebpackConfig = {
  entry: {
    /**
     * Add or remove the libraries which goes into vendor bundle file
     */
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router-dom'],
  },
  devServer: {
    // Comment the below line to run from cloud.
    host: 'localhost',

    // Comment the below line to run from local.
    //disableHostCheck: true,

    // How do we make sure we need not comment and uncomment this code everytime we run it from cloud systems 
    port: 8181
  },
 plugins: [

  ]
}
```

How do we make sure we need not comment and uncomment this code everytime we run it from cloud systems , can this be automatically picked up by webpack depending on the env we are using like local or cloud machines.

Comment: You can have several `webpack.config` and **webpack** is just pure javascript, so you can have env variables without any problem.

Comment: it not a dev or prod env more like instead of running locally on Node servers we try and run it on a web server that serves the bundle and we pick up the servers url ..

Comment: sure, i think that's what Hosar means, as in: `if (process.env.IS_CLOUD) devWebpackConfig.devServer.disableHostCheck = true; else devWebpackConfig.devServer.host = 'localhost';` & just set that `IS_CLOUD` var on your web server ... or invert it and call your env var `IS_LOCAL_DEV` & only set it locally ...

Comment: @RobertLombardo pardon me but how we set it on the web server and get it to webpack not that much familiar with webpack configs. i have a java web server serving the assets

Comment: well if webpack is run from a shell just `IS_CLOUD=true webpack <path-to-config>`. i'm not familiar with Java but if somehow you're executing webpack at runtime i guess it could be any var. or, again, skip that complication and set the `IS_LOCAL_DEV` flag instead (locally), and it being absent on the web server could do the trick :)

Comment: @RobertLombardo there is no different command i use to run it from local or cloud, it is the same command but we need to do the comment and uncomment every time we push it to cloud from local . hope i am able to explain